# equals method calling a setter, is there anti-pattern documentation?

Tags: java

Is there any ***documentation*** that states that the "equals" method should NOT call a "setter"?

I am politely asking for ~documentation~, not opinions.  To satisfy SOF guidelines about asking opinion questions.

I don't "see" it in the oracle documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

> public boolean equals(Object obj) Indicates whether some other object
> is "equal to" this one. The equals method implements an equivalence
> relation on non-null object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
> should return true.

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values
> x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x)
> returns true.

> It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x,
> y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true,
> then x.equals(z) should return true.

> It is consistent: for any
> non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y)
> consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no
> information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified. For
> any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
> possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
> reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
> and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
> whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
> contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
> have equal hash codes.
>
> Parameters: obj - the reference object with which to compare. Returns:
> true if this object is the same as the obj argument; false otherwise.
> See Also: hashCode(), HashMap

Comment: Not sure what do you expect - probably there's neither documentation that `equals` should not send email or call Police :) Seems like basic rule that the function should do what it's name says - not sure is there any 'technical' reason to not do this and if there is no such reason it's quite possible noone will put such 'good practise' into documentation

Comment: I don't think you need a documentation for this. `.equals(..)` has its purpose and it's *compare the equality* of this and given object. Stick with Single Responsibility and don't set anything from `.equals(..);`.

Comment: If the mutation changes a field that the equals-method uses for the equality check, then it could break the consistency-requirement. Other than that, it's just expected by everyone that the equals-method is a pure function with no side effects.

Comment: Great point @GiorgiTsiklauri SRP seems to be best documentation for this - however it's still nothing neither 'technical' nor literally bounded with `equals` method

Comment: Altough not documented there is the "principle of least astonishment" that states a function should behave the way that most users expect it to behave. I think an equals method which sets some fields clearly violates that, as this is unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Ha ha.  Most of these (especially SR) I have put in the code review comments.  I'll add "equals should be deterministic" (< one of my code review comments and iterated here in comment as well).  That started the "debate".

Comment: I think that m.antkowicz said it very well in the comment above. Not everything which *should not be done* should be documented. Therefore, it's possible that any documentation explicitly mentioning calling getters doesn't exist at all — which, obviously, doesn't mean that you should do it.

Comment: I agree 100% with everything here.  This is almost like computer science version of "Do I have to say on the coffee cup 'Coffee is HOT, do not pour onto your skin'" ??  And I'm arguing with others who want to pour hot coffee on their skin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ask yourself - *why do you want to do that*? - and then, look for a mistake in the answer.

You do not need (and, mostly, you will not find) a documentation enumerating things, that *should/can not be done* with/on a particular entity; rather, documentations say *what should be done* and - *how*.

Yes, there are some exceptions to the above definition, and sometimes documentations *explicitly* state, that (1) "**you should better avoid x!**" or (2) "**unfortunately you cannot do y!**"; but these usually happen when (1) some concepts are a bit equivocal, ambiguous, overlapping/cross-responsible, and they can be interpreted in a number of ways; or (2) when something seems achievable, at a glance, but it is not.

For example, `.equals(Object o)`, can be!, but:

1. should **not** be used to get/set the state;
2. should **not** be used to calculate the hash;
3. should **not** be used to do the RPC/Rest call;

and these *should not* points (thankfully) are not documented, because, since the Java 1.0 (January 1996), `.equals(Object o)` method has always had a single, very clear and sharp responsibility and purpose: to *assert the equality* of two objects, and it will continue to have that, same, sole purpose in the future, thanks to the backwards compatibility.

`.equals(Object o)` should not even be the matter of reasoning, whether *shall we use this to set the state*?, because for this, `setters` exist; hence - there is no documentation, that it *can/should not* be used for setting the state; however, it Certainly(!) should not be used for setting the state, as again - it has another purpose - to solely check the equality of `this`, and given (`o`) objects.

In addition, in a lot of the cases, you will need to @Override `.equals(Object o)` to do the corresponding comparison of your custom objects. So, how will you mix the setter and equals, both in one method? you will end up in a maintainability and readability hell.

Stick with [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Stick with Clean Code Principles and make your methods short, concise, working on a single, clear, and intuitively understandable unit of the functionality.

Stick with [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and do not try to make your car fly, and your helicopter - swim.

Think about readability, extensibility and maintainability of the class, where you override `.equals(Object o)` to set the state; it will be hell. If I, personally, would see such a thing, I will start to doubt, that the author of this code could have written getters for setting and setters for getting.

Answer (score 1):

This part stands out to me: **It is consistent**

Though it is not stated, you can safely say *equals* method should be immutable - it should not alter the state of the object, since if the state is changed, consistency is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

*Tests*, like `equals`, should not have *side-effects*. They have the requirement of being *reentrant*, callable more than once with the same result.

There is an exception to the rule, memoization, caching: a local side-effect not leaking to the external world.

There are also boolean methods, not *tests*, that advance a state: a `ResultSet#next()` yields true when a next record could be read.

You will find some requirements in *dealing* with objects having a used `equals`.
The `Map` keys for instance. `Set` of course.

I understand with "anti-pattern" you want to have some rule stated somewhere w.r.t. setters in `equals`. The closest that comes to mind are code style checkers like **SonarLint** that formulate and list such rules.